# Typescript declaring class member variable inside and outside of constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

When declaring a class member, what is the difference between instantiating one in the constructor and outside of it, with `new` keyword?

Say I have a class called 'Storage'. I'm not sure what is the difference between:

```js
class Parent {
  private readonly storage = new Storage();
}
```

```js
class Parent {
  constructor(private readonly storage: Storage) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example will always set `storage` to `new Storage()`, whereas the second example requires the caller of `new Parent()` to supply a `Storage` in the first argument to the constructor.

The first example is equivalent to this:

```
class Parent {
  // TS can infer the type of storage
  private readonly storage;

  constructor() {
    this.storage = new Storage();
  }
}

// parent.storage is set to new Storage()
const parent = new Parent();
```

whereas the second is equivalent to this:

```
class Parent {
  private readonly storage;

  constructor(storage: Storage) {
    this.storage = storage;
  }
}

declare const someOtherStorage: Storage;
// parent.storage is set to someOtherStorage, not necessarily from new Storage()
const parent = new Parent(someOtherStorage);
```

Comment: Ah, I see - so the storage needs to be initialised outside and the instance of it is plugged in the second case. Thanks, this helped me to understand it!